# How to pass variable value to json Path in Katalon Studio Rest API

Tags: rest, katalon-studio

//fetching Policy ID from Response
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()

```
def result = slurper.parseText(response.getResponseBodyContent())
def result_value = result.PolicyID
GlobalVariable.Policyid = result_value
```

//now want to use Policy ID on Verificaton

```
WS.verifyElementPropertyValue(res, 'Hist[0].Gltran.**S-HO1-20-PPHO-3820501**JV-SON-PRE-PPHO-2010-11.Cr', 20)
```

So Please help me how to pass variable value in json path on verification Level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
WS.verifyElementPropertyValue(res, GlobalVariable.Policyid, 20)
```